# Azure Storage File Share looses metadata when files updated with MS Word

Tags: c#, azure, ms-word, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

We are using File Share through Azure Storage account. As part of our application we assign ID to every file and store this ID in metadata:
[image: ID in Metadata]

Set this ID via this block of code:

```
    public static void SetId(this CloudFile cloudFile, Guid id)
    {
        cloudFile.Metadata[DocumentDbId] = id.ToString();
        cloudFile.SetMetadata();
    }
```

However when this file is edited in Microsoft Word 2013 (all the files are .docx), this metadata is wiped clean and we loose references.[image]

If I create a text file, assign it an ID in metadata, then edit it with a notepad, then this metadata stays where it should be and not wiped.

**Why editing with MS Word is wiping metadata? and how to prevent this from happening? Is there alternative way to set an arbitrary ID that is not wiped with edits?**

**UPD:** Just to clarify this is my scenario:
I mount a file share to as my local drive via `net use K: \http://myaccount.file.core.windows.net \tests /u:AZURE\myaccount uNrI0yyRxyMx`, I put a `.docx` file on the drive. In MS Azure Storage Explorer I right click the file, add metadata - any metadata, save it (tried this with C# as above, but result is just the same). Check it again to verify that the metadata was saved. Then open this file from the mounted drive in MS Word, do a change, save it. Go check the metadata on the file and there is nothing there.

But If I create a txt file, add metadata, then edit the file with a notepad++, save it. Metadata is not wiped out. So something that MS Word does to wipe the metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a [confirmation from Microsoft engineer Json Shay](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d93f4341-ccd2-4f6d-b41d-44f2801939ab/azure-storage-file-share-looses-metadata-when-files-updated-with-ms-word?forum=windowsazuredata&prof=required) that MS Word does funky stuff when writes to files:

> The reason is that MS Word (and many applications) use the Win32 ReplaceFile() API when saving a file, which is effectively a set of move+move+delete operations.  Specifically, MS Word:
>
> Writes the new version of the file into a *new* temporary file, which contains no properties: ~newfile.docx
>   Rename existingfile.docx --> existingfile_backup.docx
>   Rename ~newfile.docx --> existingfile.docx
>   Delete existingfile_backup.docx
>   The properties were written on the original existingfile.docx, which then gets renamed away, and then deleted.
>
> This is different than notepad, which is modifying the existing file in-place.